# How to prove this isomorphism?

Tags: quotient-spaces, ring-isomorphism

[image]

I know about the correspondence between ideals in $A$ that contains $\mathfrak a$ and ideals in the quotient ring $A/\mathfrak a$, but never see the isomorphism above, anyone knows how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Write $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{c}/\mathfrak{a}$ where $\mathfrak{c}$ contains $\mathfrak{a}$, then we have $A\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\rightarrow (A/\mathfrak{a})/(\mathfrak{c}/\mathfrak{a})$ is surjective as it is a composite of surjective morphism. Then it is easy to see that the kernel is $\mathfrak{c}$.

In fact $\mathfrak{c}=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{b})$

Comment: "the kernel is c" doesn't seems obvious...

Comment: The kernel of $A/\mathfrak{a}\rightarrow (A/\mathfrak{a})/(\mathfrak{c}/\mathfrak{a})$ is $\mathfrak{c}/\mathfrak{a}$ and you can see that only $\mathfrak{c}$ is mapped to $ \mathfrak{c}/\mathfrak{a} $ under the map $A\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}$